# How to update database column in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In am a new to Rails. In my application i have a balance  column of a student table. What i want to do is to add some value to that balance (not override it)
Here is my form

```html
<%= form_for @student, url: update_balance_path(@student), method: :post do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :new_balance %>
  </div>
 
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
 
<% end %>
```

And update_balance method in the studnets_contorller

```html
def updateBalance
  @student.balance += params[:new_balance]
  @student.save
 end
```

But this is not working, i tried to use (to_i) on new balance, but it doesnt help.

Comment: what do you mean "not working", post the error

Comment: Should be `params[:student][:new_balance].to_i`, assuming your model actually have a field :new_balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_for` wraps the parameters around a namespace that represent the resource and is called with the same name of the class for the instance that you pass as the parameter to the form.

If you inspect the request parameter, you will notice that the form parameters being sent are probably in the form of

```
{ "student" => { "new_balance" => 0 }}
```

and not

```
{ "new_balance" => 0 }
```

that means this line

```
@student.balance += params[:new_balance]
```

must be replaced with

```
@student.balance += params[:student][:new_balance]
```

or even better, using strong parameters, you can write

```
@student.balance += params.require(:student)[:new_balance]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def updateBalance
  @student.update_attribute(:balance, params[:new_balance])
end
```

Comment: `Model#update_attribute` is equivalent to setting the value and saving, as the user is executing in his code. That's not the issue.